# ¿Cómo unir múltiples tablas en MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, base-de-datos, mysqli

Estoy realizando un aplicación básica de control de compras y ventas y estoy intentando realizar una consulta para que me salga tipo inventario pero no he tenido resultado alguno. Este es mi consulta en mysql:

```
SELECT p.descripcion AS 'producto',SUM(dv.cantidad) AS 'salida'
FROM ventas v INNER JOIN detalle_ventas dv ON v.codigo_ventas=dv.codigo_ventas
INNER JOIN producto p ON p.codigo_producto=dv.codigo_producto
GROUP BY p.descripcion
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
-- Quiero unirlas y me salgan horizontal

SELECT p.descripcion AS 'producto',SUM(dc.cantidad) AS 'entrada'
FROM compras c INNER JOIN detalle_compras dc ON c.codigo_compras=dc.codigo_compras
INNER JOIN producto p ON p.codigo_producto=dc.codigo_producto
GROUP BY p.descripcion
```

Quiero que me salga así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quiero unir ambas consultas que me devuelve la cantidad vendida y en la otra consulta me devuelve la cantidad compra y que me quede de manera horizantal. En ambas consultas cuando los uno con UNION me queda uno debajo de otra (osea verticalmente).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Primero te voy a dar unas sugerencias con respecto a las consultas que estas poniendo de ejemplo:

1. Si no necesitas información de la tabla `ventas` o `compras`,
   entonces no las pongas dentro de la consulta (Ahora bien creo que
   las puedes necesitar para filtrar rangos de fechas por ejemplo).
2. En lo posible no agrupes consultas con descripciones o nombres, trata de
   utilizar siempre los códigos para agrupar. En tu caso puede pasar
   que dos producto tengan la misma descripción y al momento de
   agruparlos los mostraría como uno solo y esto estaría mal pues son
   dos productos distintos.

Ahora te pongo un ejemplo de como podrías realizarlo. Acá primero uno la información de ventas y compras pero les asigno un tipo, luego atraves de una subconsulta evalúo el tipo para saber si son entradas o salidas.

```
SELECT p.descripcion as producto, SUM(IF(tipo=0,m.cantidad,0)) entradas, SUM(IF(tipo=1,m.cantidad,0)) salidas, SUM(IF(tipo=0, m.cantidad, -m.cantidad)) stock
FROM
(
   SELECT 0 As tipo, dc.codigo_producto, dc.cantidad
   FROM compras c INNER JOIN detalle_compras dc ON c.codigo_compras=dc.codigo_compras
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 1 As tipo, dv.codigo_producto,dv.cantidad
   FROM ventas v INNER JOIN detalle_ventas dv ON v.codigo_ventas=dv.codigo_ventas
) AS m INNER JOIN producto p ON m.codigo_producto = p.codigo_producto
GROUP BY p.codigo_producto
```

Comment: Gracias por las sugerencias, lo tendré en cuenta, además gracias por la ayuda, con su respuesta pude solucionarlo.

Comment: OK, me alegra eso. Recuerda calificar la respuesta como correcta.

Answer (score 2):

Tu consulta de SQL tendría que ser:

```
SELECT p.descripcion AS 'producto', SUM(dc.cantidad) AS 'entrada', SUM(dv.cantidad) as 'salida'
FROM detalle_compras dc
INNER JOIN detalle_ventas dv on dv.codigo_producto = dc.codigo_producto
INNER JOIN producto p ON p.codigo_producto = dc.codigo_producto
GROUP BY p.descripcion
```

Tienes que usar las 3 tablas si quieres ver los datos en un solo resultado.